# c++ header file for defining namespace structuring

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

Coming from a c# and java background, namespaces are nothing new to me and I have come to love the organizational structuring it brings to code.

I've been doing more work in c++ lately and I try to keep my coding habits as modern as possible. I have been toying around with some sandbox code, trying some new things and I would like to get some feedback on something I've been playing around with.

What I did was create a header file that explicitly declares a series of structured namespaces. The reason I did this is I wanted to layout a predefined structuring for namespaces to be used in the project. I realize that obviously the namespaces could be declared within any classes as the classes are defined but I like the idea of predefined structuring of the namespaces, such as (just an example):

```
namespace System
{
    namespace IO
    {
    }

    namespace Serialization
    {
    }

    namespace Security
    {
        namespace Cryptography
        {
        }
    }
}
```

etc. You get the idea.

My question is: **Is there anything wrong with this approach?** I figured it could be a good practice since it follows good coding practices with encapsulation and naming, etc.

I have seen some strange comments about similar things by old-school c++ devs, such as: "You're trying to combine Java and c++", or "Namespaces are just a way to mangle type names to avoid naming conflicts". I completely disagree with those opinions and don't feel those people are fully understanding the utility that namespaces can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything inherently "wrong" with it: you're documenting the intended structure of your namespaces.

But, ultimately, it's also pretty pointless, since nothing about this file stops namespaces with the same names from being [accidentally] created in a different structure, leaving you with a broken hierarchy there with actual types declared in it, and your intended hierarchy here with nothing at all in it.

Consequently I'd probably stick to standalone documentation for this sort of thing.

Comment: Good point. I'm probably partial to the idea because of the IDE I write in (visual studio pro 2013). I make frequent use of the object browser as a tool to observe my architecture as I go, so the namespaces really stand out there, but I can see they wouldn't be as obvious if I was using a different IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a namespace hierarchy in a header file is not very useful in practice; including the header file in any other files has no effect. 
It seams to me you are trying to create a rule for people working on that project to follow, which or may or may not stick...it's all a matter of style and preference.

But there is nothing wrong with the approach it can do no harm.

Comment: Yes that pretty much is the best way to describe the intention of it. There's nothing to "force" them to follow the convention though.

Comment: The harm it could do is to provide incorrect documentation in the case that people do not follow it.